# How can I specify a proxy agent to connect?

Tags: accounts, balances, http

I'm trying to get the balance of an account with this code (dfuse example):

```
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");
global.WebSocket = require("ws");

const { createDfuseClient } = require("@dfuse/client")
const client = createDfuseClient({ 
  apiKey: "myKey", network: "mainnet" 
});

const resp = await client.stateTable("eosio.token", "myaccount", "accounts")
const { balance } = resp.rows[0].json
const message = `Balance: ${balance} (#${resp.up_to_block_num})`
```

However, I need to specify a proxy agent to connect to the endpoint, since I go via a proxy server. Anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, not sure if there is a better one.

In *http-client.js* inside *request()* I add directly the proxy agent:

```
let HttpsProxyAgent = require ('https-proxy-agent')
let proxy = 'http://X.X.X.X:PPPP'  // My proxy IP:Port
let agent_proxy = new HttpsProxyAgent (proxy)

const response = yield this.fetch(url, {
         headers: mergedHeaders,
         method,
         body: transformedBody,
         agent: agent_proxy
```

Now it connects.